# Cacti plugin to email me network traffic graphs

Tags: email, monitoring, cron, cacti, graph

I have a cacti graph set up. I'd like to receive daily emails of some graphs. What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your using linux or other unix if you use cacti & cron.

How about:

mutt -s "subject" -a image1.jpg -a image2.jpg -a page.html recipient@domain.com < /dev/null

I think as long as you refer to the images within page.html, they should automatically show in most email clients or ask you if you want to show them.

*EDIT: Probably should've noted the difference in the html tag to pick up the embedded image should look something like.

> `<img src="cid:image1.jpg">`

cid indicates to email client to look for embedded rather than locate from some URL*.

Regards
M

Answer (score 2):

Cacti has builtin functionality to export graphs (Settings => Graph Export).

I don't believe it has the ability to email the results. Only export to a local path or FTP resource.

You could however tie in the local path export with some Bash scripting to email the results.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Cacti has a folder with the graph's already generated, or if generates them as they are requested.  If it is the latter, I would recommend scripting something that scrapes the cacti webpage.

If you know a little Perl, there are two options I can think of (I think it would be the best language for this approach).  The easiest is to use WWW::Mechanize, because you can use the [WWW::Mechanize::Shell](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Shell-0.48/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Shell.pm) to generate the script for you.  [Here is a little tutorial](http://freebsd.munk.me.uk/archives/179-Command-Line-Web-Browsing-With-WWWMechanizeShell.html).

Another Perl option would be to use LWP::UserAgent, HTTP::Response, HTML::TreeBuilder.  This is probably the more traditional way to scrape data.

Answer (score 0):

THOLD (Threshold) can do this.  It's a Cacti Plugin.